# C# System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName ест много памяти

Tags: c#

У меня есть две программы которые просто проверяют наличие процессов друг-друга методом `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName` в цикле таким образом исключая возможность пользователя закрыть их без последствий, в теории всё должно работать нормально но результатом является 100% заполнение ЦП у обеих программ (при работе вместе, обе едят 40-50% ЦП).
Вопрос, есть ли какой-либо менее затратный способ? Или какой-либо способ сократить используемую память?

Comment: Как именно вызываете этот метод? Небось, в цикле `while(true)`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov , да, так. Вы знаете другой способ?

Comment: Любой метод, вызываемый бесконечно, будет жрать процессор.

Comment: Другой способ - например, использовать таймер. Или мьютекс. Или хотя бы Thread.Sleep() в цикл поставить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том что метод вызывается в бесконечном цикле `while(true)`. Любой метод вызываемый бесконечно заполняет всю допустимую для приложения память. Самое простое решение - вставить внутри цикла Sleep.

Answer (score 3):

Способ на event-ах (объект синхронизации). Будет кушать минимум ресурсов.

Код пример, приложение 1. Для приложения 2 нужно заменить все 1 на 2 и наоборот.

```
static void AppCheck()
{
    using (var appEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "App1EventName"))
    {
        appEvent.Set();

        while (true)
        {
            using (var otherAppEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "App2EventName"))
            {
                otherAppEvent.WaitOne();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("App2 started");
            var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("App2").First();
            process.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine("App2 closed");
        }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var thread = new Thread(AppCheck);
    thread.Start();

    Console.ReadKey();

    thread.Abort();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Совсем необязательно мотать бесконечный цикл. У класса Process есть метод WaitForExit и есть событие OnExited. Достаточно найти нужный процесс один раз, и потом или ждать его завершения Wait-ом, или подписаться на событие выхода, и в обработчике предпринимать действия по перезапуску, в зависимости от того, как лично вам удобнее.